# How to detect changes in WooCommerce store (react)?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, javascript, react

Since WooCommerce merged blocks in the plugin, the cart is now completely 'reactified'. Meaning I update the quantity on my cart, I see a network call to an endpoint, thigs update without reloading, they are storing things in the [store](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce-blocks/docs/third-party-developers/extensibility/data-store/README.md).

I dug around a bit and found I can actually get some information from their store like

```js
window.wp.data.select(window.wc.wcBlocksData.CART_STORE_KEY).getCartData()
```

But one thing is puzzling me a bit.

Say I'm developing my own block, dynamic type, not static(which written completely with JS using `edit` and `save` methods), and I need to 'react' (no pun intended) to some changes in the cart.

In the olden days, I'd find some event I could listen to (`wc_fragment_refresh` or `updated_wc_div`), and when something changes in the cart, I can do my own JS magic where needed using `addEventListener`. With react, that won't work.

I'm wondering if there is something similar I can use with the wc store? For instance, detect when some part of the cart store has changed, like when quantity was updated or something like that and then do my own JS thing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I read up a bit and realized I cannot mix and match (React and pure JS).

So, in the new WooCommerce they've created so-called [slot fills](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce-blocks/docs/third-party-developers/extensibility/checkout-block/slot-fills.md) that you can use to create your own react component as a separate plugin that you can then attach in [a few places](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce-blocks/docs/third-party-developers/extensibility/checkout-block/available-slot-fills.md).

Once you do that, you can use things like `useDispatch` to interact with the [cart store](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce-blocks/docs/third-party-developers/extensibility/data-store/cart.md) for instance.

Comment: I’d like to emphasize that these stores are seperate from React and can be used independently of it. As noted in your question you can `select` from stores. You can also `dispatch` and [`subscribe`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/#subscribe) (i.e. react) to them with plain JS—no React components needed. Sure, if you need to display something in an area of the page that is controlled by React it’s tricky to do so with plain JS and it’s preferable to use a provided API like slot fills as available.